# How can I get same search result as google map

Tags: google-maps, dictionary, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

When I am searching "Rudy barber Shop, New York" string in http://maps.google.com, google map showing 10 results...

But When I am using google map api in my App, It only returning two results
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Rudy%20barber%20Shop,%20New%20York&sensor=false

Now my question is that how can get the same result.

Thanks

Mandeepd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can get exactly the same results as in Google Maps.

Google Maps is a whole *application*. It uses multiple kinds of search engines behind the scenes and some may not be available as APIs, e.g. transit (public transport) directions.

Your sample request shows that you are using [The Google Geocoding API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/) which is meant for *converting **addresses** (like "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA") into geographic coordinates*. This only works for addresses, not businesses. When you put a business name in front of the address, the Geocoding API still tries to figure out where that may be, based on the part of your query that *looks* like an address. However, the Geocoding API is not meant for that use.

If you are after searching businesses around a given location, maybe you could use the [The Google Places API (Experimental)](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/) but make sure to comply with its [Requirements](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/#Limits).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but How can I reverse geo-code this  address "Rudy barber Shop, New York" with google map or google places api.
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Rudy%20Barber%20shop,%20New%20york&sensor=false

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=40.774891,-73.913702&name=Rudy%27s%20Barber%20shop&radius=500&sensor=false&key=my_key

Comment: Reverse geocoding (in the Geocoding API) is the opposite process: asking what (addresses) are around a given LatLng coordinate. Places API provides a similar search: ask for businesses within R distance from point X,Y -- see http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceSearches

Comment: @miguev can you give the update for same, if now there is any way to get search result same as in google map app.

Comment: Sure! Google Places API is now far from experimental, and you can use Text Search to get very nearly the same results as on Google Maps: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#TextSearchRequests