# how to get the complete address(es) using a business name?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I know that google maps's JSON return includes a "formatted_address" that gives you the full readable address but I've tested it on a couple of places with no success, the lat and lng coordinates aren't correct either. If I manually search it using maps.google.com it would be correct so I know the input is specific enough. How can I use the API to do this? What if the input is vague? Can I get a JSON return that includes all possible locations? (i.e. McDonalds in NYC will surely return many coordinates)

example:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=time+square+nyc&sensor=false
this returns the CORRECT coodrinates and full address that I can use.

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=amc+loews+boston&sensor=false
this does not. but of course if i just search "amc lowes boston" manually it returns the correct address on google maps.

Comment: possible duplicat of [How can I get same search result as google map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124927/how-can-i-get-same-search-result-as-google-map)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for Google Maps' [Places Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places).